# Kafka consumer needs a new Application id config after restart

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Java Kafka application that consumes from a topic. Sometimes it encounters `INVALID_FETCH_SESSION_EPOCH` error. After restarting the app it doesn't start consuming again. When I change the `StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG` it starts consuming but obviously not from the same offset. What is the reason that it does not continue consuming? Does it have anything to do with the error I get or the reason is something else?

Comment: Could you post consumer setting you are using?

Comment: @sun_007 what kind of configuration are you interested in to see. I just set some Stream configs at the start of my app, nothing else. Did you mean those configs?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this issue is caused by version incompatibility between the cluster and client. Make sure you are using correct client version that is compatible with your cluster version.

You can refer to compatibility matrix [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compatibility+Matrix)

Answer (score 0):

InvalidFetchSessionEpochException happen when the fetch session epoch of a request is different than what it expected.
If your fetch response idele for long time there is possibility to polling thread may send another new request with epoch whereas response come with different timestamp this will not stopped consuming message. You can try to set parameter to reduce buffer size, try to reduce flush size to reduce max record size to see it works for you.
You can also try with upgraded Consumer.Could you post consumer setting you are using?

Consumer offset details managed and store by zookeeper based on group id/application id so if you use same consumer id it should continue consuming from where it leftover. Whereas if you change your consumer id it will start from earliest/latest based on your setting.
If it not started consuming with same id after restart could be reason it's taking long time to rebalance, or still waiting to get max record to start consuming. Try to reduce max.request.siz , max.poll.interval.ms and max.poll.records